# How to prevent a jar from my dependency module to load and use my local Jar

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, classloader, jboss6.x

I am using JBoss-deployment-structure to load a 3rd party module as below

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <!-- This allows you to define additional dependencies, it is the same as using the Dependencies: manifest attribute -->
        <!-- Note that the export="true" is necessary if these dependencies are to be seen by the sub-deployments -->
        <!-- if export is not set or is set to false, then the dependencies are only visible to the classes in the jars in the ear lib -->
        <dependencies>
            <module name="deploy" />
        </dependencies>
        <resources>
            <resource-root path="WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </resources>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

now my module deploy contains jackson-core-2.1.3.jar and other dependency jars which I am using in my custom war project.

My custom project needs `jackson-core-2.6.0.jar` which is present in the WEB-INF/lib folder.

How can I tell JBOSS EAP6.4 to not load `jackson-core-2.1.3.jar` during classloading? What is the best way to achieve this?

One way of doing is to comment that entry in my deploy module but we cannot do that.